# CollectionViewSource from MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml

If I have something like this in my view:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <app:People x:Key="vm"></app:People> <--nvm this for now...

        <CollectionViewSource   x:Name="cvs"
                                IsSourceGrouped="True"
                                ItemsPath="Items" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Then I can do this in the codebehind:

```
private IList<Person> people;
private IList<Group<object, Person>> groupedPeople;

public People()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    people = Person.CreatePeople(200).ToList();
    groupedPeople = (from person in people
                     group person by person.City into g
                     orderby g.Key
                     select new Group<object, Person>
                     {
                         Key = g.Key.ToString(),
                         Items = g.ToList()
                     }).ToList();
    cvs.Source = groupedPeople;
}
```

This will assign the list of `gropuedPeople` to `cvs`.
I would like to move this code to my viewmodel.

My VM is properly attached to the view: `<app:People x:Key="vm"></app:People>`

Here is the ctor for the PeopleVM:

```
public PeopleVm()
        {
            people = Person.CreatePeople(200).ToList();
            groupedPeople = (from person in people
                             group person by person.City into g
                             orderby g.Key
                             select new Group<object, Person>
                             {
                                 Key = g.Key.ToString(),
                                 Items = g.ToList()
                             }).ToList();
            cvs.Source = groupedPeople;
        }
```

This does not work because the `cvs` cant be resolved here. 
Hope im clear enough here. Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered passing `cvs` to the ctor?

Comment: Thank you! I do not know how to pass cvs to the ctor, would you mind showing me how?

Comment: @artm: `CollectionViewSource` is a XAML proxy for `ICollectionView` and it shouldn't be used in view models.

Comment: @Dennis I was thinking something like `public PeopleVm(ICollectionView cvs) : this() { cvs.Source = groupedPeople;
}`

Comment: Unfortunatey I cannot acess source in this manner...